Launching modular java application in GNOME
I have a modular java application that I'm trying to launch via a desktop file in ~/.local/share/applications:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Converter
Path=/home/craig/ca.footeware.converter
Exec=sh -c "/usr/bin/java -p swt.jar:ca.footeware.converter.jar:ca.footeware.converter.temperature.jar:ca.footeware.converter.length.jar -m ca.footeware.converter/ca.footeware.converter.Converter"
Icon=/home/craig/ca.footeware.converter/converter.svg
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;
StartupWMClass=SWT

I can run gtk-launch ca.footeware.converter.desktop and it works.
I can run the exec statement at cli (in the ~/ca.footeware.converter folder) and it works.
But when I click the Converter shortcut in overview the application does not open. How do I troubleshoot this?

You could try changing the Terminal=false to Terminal=true and check for a terminal popping up. Alternatively, you could try tedirecting stdout and stderr to a file and investigating that.

With both Terminal=true and Terminal=false there is a brief flash of a terminal but the output, if any, isn't visible. I tried outputting to a logfile but one wasn't created.

I finally got a logfile but it's empty :(

How did you get the logfile? Did you redirect both stdout and stderr?

I tried both Exec=sh -v -c "/usr/bin/java -p swt.jar:ca.footeware.converter.jar:ca.footeware.converter.temperature.jar:ca.footeware.converter.length.jar -m ca.footeware.converter/ca.footeware.converter.Converter" &> logfile and Exec=sh -v -c "/usr/bin/java -p swt.jar:ca.footeware.converter.jar:ca.footeware.converter.temperature.jar:ca.footeware.converter.length.jar -m ca.footeware.converter/ca.footeware.converter.Converter &> logfile"  but got empty logfiles in both cases.

OK it's working now. Not sure if it was my edits of the exec line or if it was a reboot. But it's working now. Thanks for the help.
